# What is the font used for this grading system?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Yes, these are my grades, but I am actually going to use this font for my blog.  I'm not very good with my fonts yet, which is why I came here.  I have tried Helvetica and Arial, but it was neither of those.

Comment: This is a very suspicious question, as changing a printout of grades is something that I could see someone wanting to do. :-) Take the image to http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ It is usually spot on. Most websites rely on the fonts installed on the machine when displaying text.
If you view the page source, you can often find references to the font name or class. you could steal the css and use it on your blog. Or on the fridge. wherever these grades are going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like People Soft/Student Center. I looked through the CSS for that table, and it's Verdana, 10px, with letter-spacing set to 1px.

Answer (score 10):

To find out which font a element have in Safari (works almost the same in chrome and firefox).

Right click the text/link which you want to know the font of:

[image: select element]

next the web inspector opens, the element is already highlighted.
Now choose in the right side the computed tab and watch the property for font-family, font-size, font-weight, line-height, letter-spacing etc.

[image: inspect properties]